# PyCharm does not find python dependency when using Docker interpreter

Tags: python, docker, pycharm, ros, pythonpath

I wrote a Dockerfile. When I build the image, start a container, and go to the python console, I can access certain python dependencies (`rospy` in my case).

When I configure the docker image as a Interpreter in PyCharm, it does not find these dependencies.

Comment: Please delete your answer as it should be a part of question.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following: When I am in the container, I found what the PYTHONPATH is.

```
root@12b39bdd7ea9:/src# echo $PYTHONPATH
/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:
```

I add this PYTHONPATH to my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ros:melodic
<other stuff>
ENV PYTHONPATH="/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/:$PYTHONPATH"
```

Now PyCharm also finds the dependencies, e.g., `rospy`.